# How to store audio file byte array in internal storage?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-mediaplayer, media

I am working on a audio file transfer app where an audio file is transferred between two android devices.

I received audio file as a byte array. Now, I have an byte array of an audio file. I want to convert this byte array to audio file , then save that output audio file in device internal storage so that i can play that audio file. how can i do that in android?

Here is my code from receiving end

```
private void setMessageNotification_sound(@NonNull String topic, byte[] mp3SoundByteArray){

 // create temp file that will hold byte array
File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("audio", "mp3", getCacheDir());
tempMp3.deleteOnExit();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempMp3);
fos.write(mp3SoundByteArray);
fos.close();
```

}

here , "mp3SoundByteArray" is my received audio file as byte array. now i want to convert this byte array into audio file and after that save this fle in internal devices. how can i do this?

Comment: ??????? Your code is just doing that already. Sowny ask?

Comment: I checked transferred file in device storage but not found anywhere. So i think my code is not working. I missed something in code.

Comment: How did you search for it? A file explorer app on your device has no access to the cache dir of your app. So you can not find it then.

Comment: I didn't know this information about cache dir. I solved this problem using  "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()"